# Why do I get errcode 28 when loading huge resultsets from database?

Tags: c#, mysql

When reading the data from the MYSQL database it throws exception as given below,
(fill the dataset using ODBC dataadapter using select command)

```
ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-6.0.11-alpha-community]Error writing file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\MY237.tmp' (Err code: 28)
```

Answer (score 2):

Searching for error code 28 and MySql produces `OS Error code 28: No space left on device`. So: check if your harddisk is full.

If your drive is not full it can also be caused by permission issues. Check your write permissions. You can also try and change the temporary directory MySql uses in the option file like this:

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir=C:/temp
```

Also make sure that there are no disk quotas set up.

Comment: It can also mean "Access Denied". Check your permissions and run a filesystem check to make sure it's not corrupted.

Comment: i have read the data near about 1 million, it support to read the less data but the big data can not read throws exception

Comment: Well, then maybe MySql temporarily runs out of disk space. I don't know how much space temporary tables can consume.